# Detect key press on virtual keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a small children's game for my son that involves timing on the virtual keyboard.

Is possible to detect when a key on the virtual keyboard is pressed? I.e. get a touch notification (touchesBegan)? I do not need to know which key is pressed, just if and when the press action started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the touch events directly from the virtual keyboard. However, you could use a `UITextField` that you place offscreen, so that it's not visible and call `becomeFirstResponder` to show the keyboard. Then, as [Khomsan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882808/detect-key-press-on-virtual-keyboard/6883080#6883080) suggested, you could implement the delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:` to be notified whenever a key is pressed.

A cleaner possibility would be to write a custom `UIControl` that implements the `UIKeyInput` protocol. You would only need to provide implementations for `insertText:`, `deleteBackward` and `hasText` (for this one, you can simply always return `YES`). To make the keyboard visible, you would again have to call `becomeFirstResponder` for your custom control.

Both of these methods have in common that you only will be notified when the key is *released* (so that text is entered), not when the touch actually begins. As I said, it's not possible to get the `tochesBegan` event directly. If you need that, you would probably have to implement your own onscreen keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my suspicion that it is not possible (without custom keyboard). I already have a solution for the key-released case (textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:). 

Would it be possible to place a transparant view on top of the keyboard or is it just a waste of time to try?

Comment: I guess it would be possible, you would need to create another `UIWindow` for this however, because the keyboard has its own window, so that any views in your usual view hierarchy will always be underneath it.

Comment: FYI, I created a new UIWindow with a frame covering the keyboard and then checking hitTest. This gives me timings for when the key was pressed.

Answer (score 2):

For TextView you can use...

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

For TextField you can use...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

See UITextViewDelegate and UITextFieldDelegate on Apple website.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can just use:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //do what you need
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: What else do I need to add to get those events from a UITextView?

Comment: That will only detect touches on your own view, not the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Depanding on where you going to put it.