# How to detect two buttons long press gesture together in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have two buttons in my app.I want to detect the gesture when both buttons are hold together for at least 3 seconds. I know can detect single button long press gesture but i want to call a single function when both the buttons are pressed & hold together for few seconds. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039115/two-button-simultaneous-press-input

Comment: but how about long press gesture for 3 seconds

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882808/detect-key-press-on-virtual-keyboard

Comment: for long press you can use UILongPressGestureRecognizer and set the minimumPressDuration as 3 secs.

Comment: 2nd link is not releveant@Rishab

Comment: your solution(1st link) works for single tap just.I want to detect for longpress gesture on both buttons@Rishab

Comment: I don't see solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
@IBAction func longPress(gesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let view = gesture.view!
    print("state = \(gesture.state.rawValue)")
    if gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended && gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled {
        view.tag = 1
    } else {
        view.tag = 0
    }
    if button1.tag == 1 && button2.tag == 1 {
        print("pressed both buttons for 3 seconds")
    } else {
        print("not pressed both buttons for 3 seconds")
    }
}
```

The idea is to keep a reference to both the buttons and then use a long gesture recogniser on those buttons connect to a single action. Inside the action you get the button on which the gesture is done and then change its tag to 1. If the gesture ends or is cancelled then it is set to 0. When both the buttons are pressed then both buttons will have a tag of 1 in which case you will know that the buttons have been pressed for more than 3 secs. Note that you have to set the min duration in storyboard and keep outlets to the buttons.

You can use a different condition instead of tags to check the long pressed state if required but the same idea can be used.

In ObjC

```
-(IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) gesture {
    UIButton* button = (UIButton*)gesture.view;
    if (gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        button.tag = 1;
    } else {
        button.tag = 0;
    }
    if (button1.tag == 1 && button2.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"pressed both buttons for 3 seconds");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not pressed both buttons for 3 seconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: -[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee63018680'

Comment: Seems like you connected the button's action selector to the longPress. You should add a long press gesture recogniser instance and not the button's action selector.

Comment: I am adding same long press gesture on button using code